# ServiceNow data (API) to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

First of all, sorry if I don't explain everything super technical, I am doing my best.

I have ServiceNow REST API (a link with credentials that pulls data daily in a JSON format).

I want to use a product in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) that pulls the data weekly or daily, and stores it in a GCP product. After that, I want to wrangle the data, perhaps in another GCP product.

My questions:

1. Which GCP product should I use to pull ServiceNow data?
2. How can I do it? Do I need to code it or just use something like Dataflow?
3. Which GCP product should I use to store & wrangle the data?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You asking for recommendations. That is what the documentation is for. Your question does not even specify the API that you are using, the language, and other important details. Start with reading the announcement and then follow the documentation links:  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/cloud-migration/hybrid-and-multicloud-management-with-google-cloud-and-service-now Tip: you will be writing code, AFAIK there are no Google Cloud services that integrate ServiceNow APIs.

Comment: @JohnHanley there is a Cloud Workflows, that integrates any API, also APIs of ServiceNow.

Comment: @Pentium10 - I forgot to consider Cloud Workflows in my comment. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnHanley no need to be condescending, remember that once you were a beginner too.

Comment: @RicardoCastillo - I tried to help you. I also stated the guidelines for Stack Overflow. I am sorry that you find that a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in order of execution is this:

1. Setup [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/) entry with the API credentials you will use to connect and authorize with ServiceNow API.
2. You can use [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) to obtain data from ServiceNow API. Workflows has a snippet to pull the authorization key from Secret Manager. Also it integrates with any public API even outside of GCP, so you can connect and use ServiceNow API.
3. You can later extend your Cloud Workflow to have many steps and you can write your data to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery). Why BigQuery? Because it integrates nicely with other services like [Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep) for data wrangling, or any other pure code solution like [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).
4. To invoke your Cloud Workflows regularly you can setup a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This gave me good direction.